# Didn't find class "mono.android.app.Application"

Tags: android, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

My Xamarin Android app is already in production, people are downloading it from Google play and everything seems to be fine, except from time to time I get following errors in Google Play Developer Console :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application mono.android.app.Application:          java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mono.android.app.Application" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:559)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5119)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1418)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mono.android.app.Application" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:550)
... 11 more
```

or similar but slightly different version:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application mono.android.app.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mono.android.app.Application" on path: /mnt/asec/myapp-1/pkg.apk
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4563)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mono.android.app.Application" on path: /mnt/asec/myapp-1/pkg.apk
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:985)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
... 11 more
```

I've got zero google results for ClassNotFoundException + mono.android.app.Application. According to Developer console it comes from android 4.2 and 4.4., different devices (HTC, Samsung..), even from devices which i tested and everything works (HTC One).

Any ideas? Is this bug in mono? or Xamarin? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this an APK from Release mode?

Comment: Of course, otherwise google play wont even accept it

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `xamarin` app install in the device it is find to mono runtime support lib, if it is not installed in the device then it will stop to run so, if u have run without mono installation you can change some settings on:

> Property => Android Option

Go to Packaging and select only one `Bundle` assemblies into native code, and also go to linker and select linking is `None` then run it.

I hope it might work.